# Logic App Graph API call fails on 'invalid audience'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to make a call to the Graph API from an Azure Logic App.
I can make a call to the authentication endpoint and get a bearer token. 
However, when I use that bearer token to make the call to Graph API, I get the error message:

```
Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.
```

I've tried various examples from the MS website and other websites, but none work. 
Where am I supposed to specify the audience?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: One quick suggestion, when you are using client credential flow, make sure you don't use /me because there is no meaning of 'me' if there is no user :)-

Comment: Use v2.0 `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token` according to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret). It worked for me.

Comment: Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Hi Scgolten, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

In the first action I have made a HTTPS request to token endpoint with the details as shown below.

[image]

Then I parsed the JSON content and picked the access_token and created a new request to call MS Graph as shown below.

[image]

Since this is a client credential flow, we will be getting an App token so make sure you have configured Calendars.Read or Calendars.ReadWrite Application permissions and hit `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/events`. You should not use /me because there is no user here.

It worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I changed to the V2 endpoint. 
Now when I use the bearer token to authenticate a Graph call I get this error:
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken"
"message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217"
https://imgur.com/a/J8M3idE

Comment: This error is produced when there is an issue with the token. Make sure the token is properly given and test that token in https://jwt.ms and see if there is any issue with it